# Mark all threads that are waiting on lengthy operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm currently getting up to speed on multithreading in C# and `Task`s, etc.

I was reading the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when something jumped out at me

Under the title:

> The following are best practices when using a thread pool:

there's a statement:

> Mark all threads that are waiting on lengthy operations (such as I/O
>   flushes or resource cleanup) so that the thread pool can allocate new
>   threads instead of waiting for this one.

But no explanation of what this actually means or how to achieve this. Could someone explain this/provide an example of how I would *"mark"* a `Task` as a lengthy operation?

Comment: Total guess, but looking a the the API [maybe this is relevant?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686263(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Why is a question about the Win32 Thread Pool API tagged with .NET?

Comment: @dtb because I'm doing it in .Net.....

Comment: In .NET, you're using the .NET Thread Pool, which is not the same as the Win32 Thread Pool. Why do you think that best practices for the Win32 Thread Pool apply to the .NET Thread Pool?

Comment: Cheers @RogerRowland, but that's C++, I'm after a C# answer

Comment: If you wanted C#, you were reading the wrong article ;-)

Comment: It's relevant to me. It talks about how the Thread pool works, not how I can use it, as most of the C# articles do. I'd argue that 90% of it is relevant to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```